# Input only digits and control buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, maskedtextbox

I want to input `Salary` with any value: `550,49`, `2222,12`, `9,3` and so on. But need to use control button like this: `,`, `backspace`, `ctrl + c`, `ctrl + v`, `ctrl + a`.

`Salary` is `TextBox` with `ShortcutsEnabled = true` and event:

```
private void TbSalary_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char number = e.KeyChar;
    if ((e.KeyChar <= 47 || e.KeyChar >= 58) && number != 8 && number != 44) 
         //digits, BackSpace and ,
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

If remove this condition, the specified combinations will work. But not only numbers are entered.

Should I add tracking of all combinations here? Or is it possible to implement this task in another way?

`MaskedTextBox` requires a fixed number of characters with some "mask". But the `Salary` is different. Can be `**,**`, `******,*` or `***` and etc.

**UPDATE**

Prevent entering more than two numbers after the decimal point

```
if (number < ' ')
{
    return;
}
if (number >= '0' && number <= '9')
{
    if (this.Text.Contains(',') 
        && this.SelectionLength == 0
        && this.SelectionStart > this.Text.IndexOf(',')
        && this.Text.Length - this.Text.IndexOf(',') > 2)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, don't use *magic numbers* like `47`, let's work with *characters*. We should allow these characters:

- `'0'..'9'` range (numbers)
- control characters (which are below space `' '`) for `tab`, `backspace` etc.
- `','` (comma) as a decimal separator

All the other characters should be banned.

**Code:**

```
private void TbSalary_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    char number = e.KeyChar;
    TextBox box = sender as TextBox;

    if (number >= '0' && number <= '9' || number < ' ')
        return; // numbers as well as backspaces, tabs: business as usual
    else if (number == ',') {  
        // We don't want to allow several commas, right?
        int p = box.Text.IndexOf(',');

        // So if we have a comma already...
        if (p >= 0) { 
            // ... we don't add another one
            e.Handled = true;

            // but place caret after the comma position
            box.SelectionStart = p + 1;
            box.SelectionLength = 0;  
        }  
        else if (box.SelectionStart == 0) {
            // if we don't have comma and we try to add comma at the 1st position 
            e.Handled = true;

            // let's add it as "0,"
            box.Text = "0," + box.Text.Substring(box.SelectionLength);
            box.SelectionStart = 2;
       } 
    }
    else  
        e.Handled = true; // all the other characters (like '+', 'p') are banned
}
```

Please, note, that there is possibility to **Paste** *incorrect value* (say, `"bla-bla-bla"`) into `TbSalary` `TextBox`; to prevent it you can use `TextChanged` event:

```
private void TbSalary_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextBox box = sender as TextBox;

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  bool hasComma = false;

  foreach (var c in box.Text)
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
      sb.Append(c);
    else if (c == ',' && !hasComma) {
      hasComma = true;

      if (sb.Length <= 0) // we don't start from comma
        sb.Append('0');

      sb.Append(c);
    }

  string text = sb.ToString();

  if (!text.Equals(box.Text))
    box.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: Could you tell me why in my case `Ctrl` combinations were blocked? For full control lacks case, when comma impose the first. Either by mistake or implies `0,**`

Comment: @Viewed: if you want to allow all control keys (like `backspace`, `ctrl+v` etc.) you should allow control characters (that are *below space*): `number < ' '`

Comment: @Viewed: you can easily implement a case when we are at the 1st position and press comma and want to have `"0,..."` instead of `",..."`   (see my edit)

Comment: Take a look at my attempt to prohibit entering more than two numbers after the decimal point (updated post).

Comment: @Viewed: I'm sorry, I don't buy it. What if I have `"123456,78"` the caret is after `2` - `"12|3456,78"` and I press `0`? If you start *tuning* the solution you 
should operate with `box.SelectionStart` and `box.SelectionLength`. In you case: if comma is present and not within selection, if caret position is after the comma then...

Comment: @Viewed: I'm sorry, but no. What if you press `backspace` (`number < ' '`) and you have comma conditions met? Another case is when you select the entire text, have conditions for comma met and press `1`.

Comment: Yes, I showed the wrong code. Made a separate condition.

Comment: @Viewed: add `SelectionLength == 0` condition into your current soultion (update); I can select **2** last digits after the comma `"123,|45|"` (`|..|` means selection) and press `6`; expected outcome is `"123,6"` when your code will do nothing (`e.Handled = true;`)